Custom Namespace in Laravel 11: Issue with Artisan Commands
I've been working with Laravel 11 and decided to change the default namespace ("App") to a custom one ("Aggp"). I made the necessary adjustments in the composer file and updated all existing files accordingly. The application is functioning smoothly with the custom namespace.
However, I've encountered an issue where the codes generated through artisan commands still use the default namespace. I've searched extensively but couldn't find a solution to change this setting.
I'd greatly appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this matter.

Have you run composer dump-autoload? You can check the namespace being used by your project with app()->getNamespace(). If that is still returning "App" you need to find out why.

Yes, i run it and works well, application works with new namespace and only issue is when generating models and resources through the artisan it use the old default namespace.

What do you get when you run app()->getNamespace? Artisan commands to generate new code use "stubs" (there's a folder in the top level of the project) and in there the {namespace} placeholder is replaced with the namespace path coming from the Application class. If you get the correct namespace from getNamespace it should be the same for the generated code.

App()->getNamespace() returns the defalut namespace (\App). I have no idea how to change it to new one. Do you have any idea ?

Add to your question the section of the composer.json you changed to have Aggp instead of App.

What I did:
I have a custom class that extends the Application and use that in the bootstrap/app.php.
<?php

namespace Support;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class BaseApplication extends Application
{
    protected $namespace = 'Aggp\\';

    public function path($path = '')
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app/Aggp'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }
}

In your bootstrap/app.php you should have:

return \Support\BaseApplication::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting()
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {})

    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


You probably won't have the Support namespace so you need to fix that to your own needs :)
Hope this helps someone!

To change the custom namespace update the autoload psr-4 variable in composer.json file.
Update all the files wherever the namespace is included.
And make sure to run the following command:
composer dump-autoload

I hope this works for your problem.
